# Google Cloud Endpoint - How to create handler to call endpoints from cron

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, android-studio, cron

**UPDATED QUESTION**

I can't find any sample or tutorial to call endpoints from cron via handler.

Don't have any experience with Backend services!!

**Old description and code**
I have a GCE module deployed on AppEngine via Android Studio for my Android App.
I am able to create and fetch info via endpoint client stubs in my Android app.
For cleaning data on app engine, there is a simple method that compares and delete any data older than 5 days.
This method is running fine if called through java code.

There is an issue with the cron that I have created. I am not sure if it is running at all or calling the right method inside my endpoint class. Need help in running it automatically.

I have different ways to declare method name and path along with url entry in cron, but no success yet.

Other solutions on stackoverflow are not clear to me.

Endpoint class method

```
@ApiMethod(name = "cron.cleanData", path="cron/cleanData")
    public void cleanData(@Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString,
                                @Nullable @Named("count") Integer count) throws NotFoundException {
        System.out.print("cleanData... called");
        CollectionResponse<Data> listData = listData(cursorString, count);
        for (Data data : listData.getItems()) {
            System.out.print("for..");
                if(isOld(data.getTime(), data.getDate())){
                    removeData(data.getId());
                    System.out.print("removed.."+data.getId());
                }
        }
    }
```

cron.xml inside WEB-INF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
    <cron>
        <url>/cleanData</url>
        <description>Clean Storage</description>
        <schedule>every 1 minutes</schedule>
        <timezone>America/Hawaii</timezone>
    </cron>
</cronentries>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services</param-name>
            <param-value><MY_PACKAGE>.MyEndpoint</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>cron</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/cron/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cron job for Google Appengine Endpoints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36305948/cron-job-for-google-appengine-endpoints)

Comment: I didn't understand the answer there

Comment: can you share any code example?

Comment: Any updates? Even I don't know how. I searched everywhere and all they do is reply the same thing that says from the GCE docs.

Answer (score 0):

> You cannot call a Google Cloud Endpoint from a cron job. Instead, you
>   should issue a request to a target that is served by a handler that's
>   specified in your app's configuration file or in a dispatch file. That
>   handler then calls the appropriate endpoint class and method.

You can find more details [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron#Java_calling_google_cloud_endpoints).

Comment: I have no idea of backend :( . Can you share some example with me?

Comment: Just create your cron job as a regular Servlet. Check out [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/) tutorial. Anyway, if you do not have experience with server side development, you will have to invest some time.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36373975/1668204) to a similar question may help.

Comment: I have seen that. Not clear to me. Is there any issue at my end while deploying? I am using Android Studio for deploying. But currently testing locally on my machine using the built and run action.

Comment: No experience with servers :(